# hide selected language in drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu where the user can change their language preference. I'd like to have it so that the language which is selected will not show in the drop-down menu. This is my html:

```
<li>
   <a class="languages main-links">
       <img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/LANGUAGE_CODE.png" alt="">
    LANGUAGE_NAME
   </a>
   <ul class="nav-dropdown">
      <li><a onClick="changeLanguage('en')" hreflang="en"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/en.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_EN</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="changeLanguage('zh-cn')" hreflang="zh-cn"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/zh-cn.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_ZH_CN</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="changeLanguage('zh-hk')" hreflang="zh-hk"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/zh-hk.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_ZH_HK</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="changeLanguage('jp-jp')" hreflang="jp-jp"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/jp-jp.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_JP_JP</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="changeLanguage('ko-kr')" hreflang="ko-kr"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/ko-kr.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_KO_KR</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="changeLanguage('th-th')" hreflang="th-th"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/th-th.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_TH_TH</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="changeLanguage('zh-cn')" hreflang="zh-cn"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/malaysia.png" alt="">malaysia</a></li>
   </ul>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
function changeLanguage(lang) {
    if (languageOptions.indexOf(lang) === -1) {
        lang:selected.hide();
        return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
    window.location.href = '/' + lang;
}
```

When I've looked online I only find ways to achieve this using jQuery, how can I achieve this with plain JavaScript? The way I have tried in my code doesn't work.

Comment: Once you do `window.location.href = '/' + lang;` Page will be redirected

Comment: So should I try to hide the selected language after then?

Comment: Once it is redirected, it will load a new page. Control from this `changeLanguage` will be gone.

Comment: So are you saying I need to use a new function? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to have it so that the language which is selected will not
>   show in the drop-down menu.

You can bind the `click` event on `li`s

```
$( ".nav-dropdown li[hreflang]" ).click( function(){
   //$(this).hide(); //to hide the clicked li, but not required since page will be redirected anyways
   var lang = $(this).attr("hreflang");
   localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);

   window.location.href = '/' + lang;
});
```

Now once you come back to this page again, just check your `localStorage` value to hide the selected language

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $( ".nav-dropdown li[hreflang='" + localStorage.getItem('lang') + "']" ).hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeLanguage(lang){
lang.parentNode.style.display="none";
  
}
```

```html
<li><a class="languages main-links"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/LANGUAGE_CODE.png" alt="">LANGUAGE_NAME</a>
                        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                            <li><a onClick="changeLanguage(this)" hreflang="en"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/en.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_EN</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="changeLanguage(this)" hreflang="zh-cn"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/zh-cn.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_ZH_CN</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="changeLanguage(this)" hreflang="zh-hk"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/zh-hk.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_ZH_HK</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="changeLanguage(this)" hreflang="jp-jp"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/jp-jp.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_JP_JP</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="changeLanguage(this)" hreflang="ko-kr"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/ko-kr.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_KO_KR</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="changeLanguage(this)" hreflang="th-th"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/th-th.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_TH_TH</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="changeLanguage(this)" hreflang="zh-cn"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/malaysia.png" alt="">malaysia</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a class="languages main-links"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/LANGUAGE_CODE.png" alt="">LANGUAGE_NAME</a>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown">
       <li><a  hreflang="en"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/en.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_EN</a></li>
       <li><a hreflang="zh-cn"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/zh-cn.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_ZH_CN</a></li>
       <li><a  hreflang="zh-hk"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/zh-hk.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_ZH_HK</a></li>
       <li><a  hreflang="jp-jp"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/jp-jp.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_JP_JP</a></li>
       <li><a  hreflang="ko-kr"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/ko-kr.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_KO_KR</a></li>
       <li><a  hreflang="th-th"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/th-th.png" alt="">NAVIGATION_TH_TH</a></li>
       <li><a hreflang="zh-cn"><img class="flag" src="assets/img/flags/malaysia.png" alt="">malaysia</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
var languges = document.querySelector(".nav-dropdown");

   //using just one event listener to promote "DRY" code
   //we can target the LIs and their inner As from the UL
   languges.addEventListener("click", function (e)
   {
      var target = e.target; //this is the element the event is fired on

      if(target.hasAttribute("hreflang"))
      {
         var lang = target.getAttribute("hreflang");
         target.parentElement.style.display = "none";
         localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
         window.location.href = '/' + lang; //
      }
   })
```